# How to build qt .lib files out of .prl files

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2019, qtcharts

I'm new to Qt. I'm under Win 10, 64bit, using Visual Studio 2019.

I installed Qt 5.15.1 a while ago to work on an open source project. Python and CMake are also installed. vcvarsall.bat was also executed.

Now I'm working on a new project where I need QtCharts. I found that QtCharts was not installed by default. So I installed QtCharts with the Qt MaintenanceTool.exe. After that, I was expecting to see the *.lib files added to the lib folder but what I see are added *.prl files.

What is the next step for me to get the *.lib files.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the .lib files I was expecting are there in the lib folder. I'm not sure how and when they got there. I re-checked in the lib folder after I succesfully built Qt provided examples that use QtCharts within Qt Creator. The dates on the files are from back to September 2020, though. Like if the files had been copied from another folder or from an archive.

Anyway. My problem is solved.

Comment: The dates on those files are build dates. I’d also suggest that you forget about qmake and switch to cmake. You’ll have a much easier time - such low level details will be of mostly no concern.